# Status does not change when I delete data from here

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [products, setProducts] = useMangeProduct([]);
const handelDeleteProduct = id => {
        const url = `https://fierce-everglades-14403.herokuapp.com/product/${id}`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data?.acknowledged === true) {
                    const restProducts = products.filter(product => product._id !== id)
                    setProducts(restProducts);
                    toast.error('Product Delete successfully')
                }
            })
    }
```

** state Change**
data deleted but state not change.
if I reload the page so I can see my data is deleted. But when I click on the delete button, there is no change.

Comment: would you please add some explanation about the question of what you need exactly, adding just code won't help you get an answer!

Comment: Do you get the data in console.log()?

Comment: The issue is likely to be in `setProducts`, you need to include that too.

Answer (score 1):

You mean that way?

```
let sure = confirm('Do you want to delete your constumer?');
if (sure) {
    // code to send fetch to your server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this for Anchor Link. Hope that helps.

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this User?')) {return true;}else{event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();};"> Delete User </a>
```